# Footer along with Searchbar not properly shown in FlatList

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I have this set of components:

```
render() {
        return (
            <InstantSearch
                appId="29FLVJV5X9"
                apiKey="f2534ea79a28d8469f4e81d546297d39"
                indexName="prod_conferences"
                style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Configure filters={`startDateUnix>${TODAY}`} hitsPerPage={10} />
                <SearchBox />
                <LoadingIndicator />
                <Conferences/>
            </InstantSearch>)
    }
```

Where `<InstantSearch>` is a simple `<View>`

My Conferences:

```
export default connectInfiniteHits(({ hits, hasMore, refine }) => {

  const LoadMoreFooter = connectStateResults(
    ({ searching }) =>
      !searching ? <View style={s.loadMoreButtonContainer}>
        <Divider style={s.loadMoreButtonDivider} />
        <Button transparent color={'#53acfe'} title={'Load more confs...'} onPress={() => refine()} />
      </View> : null
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={hits}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.objectID}
      ListFooterComponent={<LoadMoreFooter />}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <ConferenceItem {...item} />
      }
    />
  );
});
```

And `<SearchBox>` is a simple `<SearchBar>` from RN-elements.
The problem is, after I added the SearchBox, my footer is never shown, the scroll "stops" before showing the footer.

With SearchBar(not working):
[image]

Without SearchBar (working):
[image]

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to add extra padding to your FooterComponent? If you add some paddingBottom to the <LoadMoreFooter /> or increase its height this should solve your problem. Plus maybe you can do this in a more elegant manner using contentInset prop https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentinset

Comment: Yeah, that's the exact same solution I have! But this seems so hacky to me, I thought that probably there was a more elegant solution (like if you use a bottomBar or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

#### Method 1

Add `flex: 1` to the parent view:

```
<InstantSearch style={{ flex: 1 }}>
```

In your `InstantSearch`, make sure you pass the style to the outermost view:

```
const InstantSearch = props => <View style={props.style}>...
```

#### Method 2

Move your `SearchBox` to the `ListHeaderComponent` prop of `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList ListHeaderComponent={() => <SearchBox />} ...
```

#### Method 3

Give your `SearchBox` the following style:

```
{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }
```

See Method 1 on how to pass it to the wrapped `View`. If `SearchBox` is from a third party module, then just wrap it with a `View`:

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }}>
  <SearchBox />
</View>
```

#### Method 4

Use `SectionList` instead of `FlatList` to avoid `SearchBox` getting scrolled down (as is with Method 2).

```
<SectionList
  renderSectionHeader={SearchBox}
  sections={[{ data: hits }]}
```

It has a [slightly different API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) so I changed the data shape to pass to `sections` prop. Further changes might be required.

#### EDIT

You have an extra `View` that you did not include in OP, and you did not move the `SearchBox` to `renderSectionHeader`. Everything on top that occupies space should be moved from `RootContainer` to `ConferenceList`:

```
<SectionList
  sections={groupAndSortConferences(hits)}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <ConferenceItem {...item} />}
  keyExtractor={item => item.uuid}
  ListFooterComponent={<LoadMoreFooter />}
  renderSectionHeader={() => (
    <View>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <View style={{ height: 24, backgroundColor: '#FFCA04' }} />}
      <SearchBox />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

The hardcoded `View` you added for ios to replace the status bar seems hacky though, but that's a separate problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it doesn't work. In method 1, the InstantSearch component is from a third party library, so I cannot edit it. And method 2 is not okay, since if I scroll downwards when already on top, on ios, the searchBox gets pulled down altogether, which is a behavior that sucks. Any other sugestions? Thanks

Comment: added 2 more methods. Also check the `InstantSearch` API/source code, it might already be assigning a prop to the `View` container's style.

Comment: Still no luck, tried it all :( If it helps, this is an open source project, the component is this one: https://github.com/leonardo2204/confstech-mobile/blob/retry/Components/ConferenceList/ConferenceList.js#L46

Comment: The highlighted line is a hacky workaround I thought, but I'm pretty sure there is a much better option then hardcoding some "random" number! Thanks again

Comment: see edit in post. Commit your updated code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again for taking your time, but the problem is that I already have a sectionHeader (the month display). Anyway, even if I didn't if I pull down the list it would pull the SearchBox along, which is something I don't want to happen. Any other idea? Thank you

Comment: Nest another section list within the first section list. i.e. in the edited code above, change `renderItem` to a SectionList with `ConferenceItem` for `renderItem` and the month display for `renderSectionHeader `.